# Zend Framework: How to load existing project into ZF's CLI?

Tags: php, zend-framework, console

In ZF you create a project by running this command:

```
zf create project MyProjectName
```

But how does one load a project that already exists?

I don't see anything in the documentation that specifies a `zf load project` or `zf set project` or something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible to my knowledge, but on the to-do list

See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7940

Comment: So, if I create a project and then reset my terminal session or restart my computer, I will never be able to use the Zend_Tool commands again for that project?

Comment: @Thomas That would be pointless wouldn't it? When creating a new Project with Zend_Tool, it will create an XML file. Whenever you use Zend_Tool it will update this file accordingly. So as long as the file is there you can use Zend_Tool with that project. When you restart your computer, you don't have to load this file. Zend_Tool knows where it is. What *doesn't work* yet, is importing an *existing* project for that no XML file exists yet, because it is much more diffcult to create the XML file for a half done project than for a vanilla one ( = always the same file).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had accidentally removed that .zfproject.xml without knowing it. When I was in my project directory Zend_Tool would tell me 'A project profile was not found' and it didn't seem like there was any way to tell ZF what project to load. Restoring the XML file worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create another zf project in a different directory and copy the xml file into the the folder where it's missing. in the xml file, everything is relative, so you don't have to worry about the newly dummy project's path and others.